# Erros de Dependências

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependências

Estou com um problema com as dependecias do projeto, ontem trabalhei normalmente e hoje, logo que abri o projeto e buildei, os erros apareceram...

Tentei realizar o `clear`, reinstalar os `Nugets`, `restore Nugets`, fechei aplicação, apaguei a aplicação e realizei o `clone` novamente.

Mesmo tendo realizado estes itens as dependências continuam com erro.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Opa, clica com o botão direito no projeto e vai em propriedades e confirma se está setado o framework ali em estrutura de destino

Comment: @RafaelScheffer Realizei algumas abordagens. mas no final eu realizei o upgrade no nuget e após o down-grade. Dessa forma Consegui compilar a Aplicação.